# Output filter results into a text box

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a web apps script with a field that accepts user input and returns the result(s). I need it to list all the results associated with the input query.

Things I've tried doing:

1. I've assigned an actual order number to orderInput and I was able to get the results I wanted it to return using Logger.log(orderMatch) so I know it works.
2. I wasn't sure if I was running into a formatting issue so I tried converting orderInput to a string with orderInput.toString() and that didn't work.
3. At first I was trying to display it in a disabled input field and that didn't work so I tried using a textarea but that didn't work either.
4. I've also tried moving the `document.getElementById("orderResults").value = (orderMatch);
   M.updateTextFields();` in various places between `return item[0] === orderInput
   });`
5. I was using `document.getElementById("orderNumber").addEventListener("change",orderLookup);` to trigger the script from running but I also tried creating a button with `onclick="orderLookup()"` but that didn't work.

This is my script:

```
  function orderLookup() {

    var orderSheet = "Google Spreadsheet URL"

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(orderSheet);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
    var originalSheet = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();

    var orderInput = document.getElementById("orderNumber").value;

    var orderMatch = originalSheet.filter(function(item) {
      return item[0] === orderInput
    });

document.getElementById("orderResults").value = (orderMatch);
    M.updateTextFields();
  }
```

As for my HTML:

```
      <div class="input-field col s2">
        <input value="" id="orderNumber" type="text" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="orderNumber">Enter Order Number</label>
      </div>

      <center style="float:left;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;">
        <h6><b>Results</b></h6>
        <textarea id="orderResults" rows="10" cols="45" disabled="disabled" style="width:100%; height:auto"></textarea>
      </center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- You want to look for the data in the sheet when `Enter Order Number` is clicked.
- You want to look for rows where first column matches the input you provided.
- You want all the data in the row to show up in the `<textarea>` element.

A possible solution would be the following:

1. Create an `onclick` event in the `label`, which will run a function on the client side:

```
<label class="active" for="orderNumber" onclick="search()">Enter Order Number</label>
```

2. Next, the following function is run by the onclick event. This function calls a server-side function (orderLookup) which will look for matching data in the sheet and return the results.

```
function search() {
  var input = document.getElementById("orderNumber").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showResults).orderLookup(input);
}
```

3. Here is function `orderLookup`:

```
function orderLookup(input) {
  var orderSheet = "Google Spreadsheet URL"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(orderSheet);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
  var values = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var orderMatch = values.filter(function(item) {
    return item[0] === input
  });
  return orderMatch;
}
```

4. If `orderLookup` returns a value, another client-side function will run, which will get the matching data as a parameter, and will write it to the `<textarea>`:

```
function showResults(orderMatch) {
  var matches = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < orderMatch.length; i++) {
    matches = matches.concat(orderMatch[i], "\n");
  }
  document.getElementById("orderResults").value = matches;
}
```

So, full code would be the following:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="input-field col s2">
        <input value="" id="orderNumber" type="text" class="validate">
        <label class="active" for="orderNumber" onclick="search()">Enter Order Number</label>
      </div>

      <center style="float:left;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;">
        <h6><b>Results</b></h6>
        <textarea id="orderResults" rows="10" cols="45" disabled="disabled" style="width:100%; height:auto"></textarea>
      </center>    
  </body>
  <script>
    function search() {
      var input = document.getElementById("orderNumber").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showResults).orderLookup(input);
    }
    function showResults(orderMatch) {
      var matches = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < orderMatch.length; i++) {
        matches = matches.concat(orderMatch[i], "\n");
      }
      document.getElementById("orderResults").value = matches;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

> Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function orderLookup(input) {
  var orderSheet = "Google Spreadsheet URL"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(orderSheet);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");
  var values = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var orderMatch = values.filter(function(item) {
    return item[0] === input;
  });
  return orderMatch;
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for going in depth step by step to help me understand. It's very close!! The onclick() trigger wasn't working for me but after replacing it with a button, it worked. Although this was able to return a value, it returns only the first match. Is there a way to get it to list all results that match the query? My original code was able to log all results but with yours, I have to adjust the [0] in orderMatch (index.html) to different numbers until I get a return that states "undefined".

Comment: @razaclas, I have updated my answer so that it writes all matches, not only the first one. Let me now if that works for you.

Comment: I was able to successfully output a list of all the various results that matched the search query. I ran into another formatting issue where the list of results repeats the order number, date assigned, etc., for each result which I'm trying to figure out now. Thank you for assisting me with the initial issue I had with this, which was getting an output to display in a "return" field!

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks to me like your mixing server side functions with client side functions and I'm guessing that since you provide html code and script that you trying to run is client side.

```
function orderLookup() {
  var orderSheet = "Google Spreadsheet URL"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(orderSheet);//Server side function
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");//Server side function
  var originalSheet = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();//Server Side function
  var orderInput = document.getElementById("orderNumber").value;//Client Side Function
  var orderMatch = originalSheet.filter(function(item) {return item[0]===orderInput});//could be either
  document.getElementById("orderResults").value = (orderMatch);
  M.updateTextFields();//dont know
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me Cooper. Prior to this, I had no idea that there were two types of functions and I didn't understand why similar looking functions went into a <script> tag in html and others went into a .gs file. I'll be studying this more!

Comment: The functions that you find in the Google Apps Script documentation are server side.  Many JavaScript functions will work server side.  Google Apps script  is currently based up [Javascript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6)